# EF Subquery No Navigation Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Im trying to compute a boolean field based on a subquery

```
  var dtfs = cntx.Set<Models.DocTypeField>()
                 .Include(dtf => dtf.Field)
                 .Where(dtf => dtf.DocTypeId == docTypeId)
                 .Select(dtf => new
            {
                DocTypeField = dtf,
                HasData = (cntx.Set<Models.DocumentData>()
                               .Any(dd => dd.DocTypeId == dtf.DocTypeId 
                                 && dd.DataValues.Any(ddv => ddv.FieldId == dtf.FieldId)))
            });
```

There is no navigation property(or traversable path) between `DocTypeField` and `DocumentData`. When I run the query above I get the following exception:

Test method

```
Core.Sebring.DataAccess.Ef.Test.EF_DocTypeDALTest.EF_DocTypeDALTest_GetDocTypeIndexes
 threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: 
  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
  'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Core.Sebring.Models.DocumentData] 
     Set[DocumentData]()' method, and this method cannot be translated 
     into a store expression.
```

Is there a linq to entity way of accomplishing the above query? I would rather not add a navigation property(or traversable path) between `DocTypeField` and `DocumentData`, if possible.

****UPDATE 1****
As a work around I did

```
class FieldDocTypeField
    {
        public int DocTypeFieldId { get; set; }
        public int DocTypeId { get; set; }
        public int FieldDataType { get; set; }
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public byte[] LastChanged { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public bool HasData { get; set; }
    }

var dtfs = cntx.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<FieldDocTypeField>(@"select dtf.*,f.*,
            HasData = (CASE  WHEN EXISTS(Select DocumentDataValue.FieldId 
            from DocumentData 
            inner join DocumentDataValue on DocumentData.DocumentDataId=DocumentDataValue.DocumentDataId
            where DocumentData.DocTypeId = @DocTypeId AND dtf.FieldId = 1) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)
            from DocTypeField dtf
            inner join Field f on dtf.FieldId = f.FieldId WHERE dtf.DocTypeId=@DocTypeId", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DocTypeId", docTypeId));

            foreach (var dtf in dtfs)
            {
                docTypeFields.Add(new Models.DocTypeField
                {
                    DocTypeFieldId = dtf.DocTypeFieldId,
                    DocTypeId = dtf.DocTypeId,
                    FieldDataType = dtf.FieldDataType,
                    FieldId = dtf.FieldId,
                    LastChanged = dtf.LastChanged,
                    Required = dtf.Required,
                    FieldName = dtf.FieldName,
                    HasData = dtf.HasData
                });
            }
```

Its not so nice but it works and accomplishes the same things. I could not find a way to do the above using linq to entities without adding a nav property between `DocTypeField` and `DocumentData` entities.

Comment: I can assure you that when you finish the project and return to it a few months later, you won't understand this query. Same for other developers in the project.

Comment: Also, what type is cntx variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the data in memory first and then do the 2nd `select`.

```
var dtfs = cntx.Set<Models.DocTypeField>()
    .Include(dtf => dtf.Field)
    .Where(dtf => dtf.DocTypeId == docTypeId)
    .ToList() // pull the data to memory and then the following select can execute successfully.
    .Select(dtf => new
    {
        DocTypeField = dtf,
        HasData = (cntx.Set<Models.DocumentData>()
            .Any(dd => dd.DocTypeId == dtf.DocTypeId
                       && dd.DataValues.Any(ddv => ddv.FieldId == dtf.FieldId)))
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not want 2 queries either.

Comment: @user1916697 that is one query, the 2nd query queries from memory not db, same as you do normal linq on list.